# Automatic app opening + power, home button not working J Max [SM-T285YD]

Tags: buttons, operating-system

My device is **Samsung J Max (SM-T285YD)**. I can go onto download mode, recovery mode. Even after restart power button also working. But after sometimes suddenly it opens chrome, google automatically. Even when i am starting an application it is coming back to home automatically. I am not touching anything. During this time power and home buttons are not working. Even after factory reset the problem remains same. I wiped all files even the os and installed the firmware in the morning. The whole day it was fine. Now at night it is showing the same problem. What should i do ?

Comment: your buttons are wet/short circuited. dry smartphone in sun

Comment: Done..but no effect

Comment: wait some weeks